# Is there a way to import component-specific scss file from VMware Clarity?

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm trying to create React Components with VMWare Clarity styles. Is there a way to import component-specific .scss instead of importing clr-ui.min.css?

Comment: Take a look at the **Custom Themes** section here: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/themes. This is how you would integrate the scss files into a standard angular cli app **if you were building a custom theme with the Clarity SCSS**. I'm not real familiar with how React apps are built for dev and production though so you will have to figure out where to import the Clarity scss for your app.

Comment: if you use the version of @clr/ui installed via NPM you cannot, if you relly need it you could try to use ths source files. To be honest I don't know if it's worth. the whole CSS file is around 400KB and webpack is able to bundle only you really need

Answer (score 0):

It is currently non-trivial to isolate styles for Clarity on a per-component basis. There may be a few options for you, which all should be considered carefully. I'm not familiar enough with React build tooling to know how well these may work.

1. Use a tool like https://github.com/uncss/uncss that can remove unused CSS from your bundles.
2. Build your own version of Clarity that imports only what you need, but know that this is unsupported unless you follow the themes documentation https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/themes. In the future, we plan to make this easier but its a major overhaul.
3. Copy our SCSS files into your project, but this means you lose upgradability for Clarity in the future.